# How to use JDK from dependency in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, checker-framework

I'm trying to use the [Checker Framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#gradle) with Gradle. The official docs are expecting an environment variable to point to the annotated JDK:

```
options.forkOptions.executable = "$CHECKERFRAMEWORK/checker/bin/javac"
```

However, [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33270054/618906) to manage the dependency on Checker Framework through Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    checker "org.checkerframework:checker:1.9.6"
    checker 'org.checkerframework:jdk8:1.9.6'
    compile configurations.checker.dependencies
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
}
```

How can I best get the path to javac in Gradle from the dependency on `org.checkerframework:jdk8`?

Comment: There is no executable javac in the jar for dependency jdk8:1.9.6 The checker documentation you linked to probably expects you to download the checkerframework onto your file system and set the path to javac in your build.gradle.

Comment: The SO answer you linked to is using `-Xbootclasspath` as shown in the maven example just above the gradle section of the checker documentation you linked to. It would seem what the other SO answer shows is the only way to do it, if you want to use jdk8 dependency.